# Passing mysqli to class doesn't show results

Tags: php, mysqli

I have problem passing mysqli to my class. It works fine when it's passing to non-class.
I tried to use Dependency injection here but for some reason it won't show results when printed, it's just a blank page.

Here is my connect.php

```
   <?php
$db = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'audiologiska_kliniken');

if($db->connect_errno > 0){
    die('Ett fel inträffade [' . $db->connect_error . ']');
}
```

My test class:

```
   <?php
    //error_reporting(0);
    include '../include/connect.php';


    class test
    {
        private $mysqli;

        function __construct(mysqli $db)
        {
            $this->mysqli = $db;
            $this->testing();
        }
        function testing()
        {
            $result = $this->mysqli->query("Select * from person");
                print_r($result);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are not instantiating test in order to use it

```
include '../include/connect.php';

class test
{
    private $mysqli;

    function __construct(mysqli $db)
    {
        $this->mysqli = $db;
        $this->testing();
    }
    function testing()
    {
        $result = $this->mysqli->query("Select * from person");
            print_r($result);
    }
}

new test($db);
```

Comment: But I'm calling it on the same class, why would I need to do that?

Comment: because every class is blueprint for an object, in other words it is static ! as long as it is not instantiated using the "new" keyword it can't be processed to runtime

Comment: I tried `new test($db);` in the constructor instead of `$this->testing();`. It still didn't show any results

Comment: @David.J you input new test ($db) after test class not inside it !